# Ubuntu 18.04 and LAN file sharing

Tags: networking

I have 2 machines running Ubuntu 18.04, a Desktop and a Laptop. And a number of PCs running linux mint 19.1.

The Desktop is an AMD based 64 bit machine. The Laptop is Intel based 64 bit. Both machines were installed from the same source Ubuntu18.04.2.iso

I create the share by right clicking the folder and setting up samba share. I have also tried making entries in /etc/samba/smb.conf, to no avail. NOT both together.

When I share a folder on the Laptop it is accessible on all machines. When I do the same on the Desktop It is visible but inaccessible to all machines.

Mint works fine for sharing to all machines.

I tried a fresh install on a separate Partion and drive on the Desktop. The same problem persists. I then replaced this with Mint 19.1 Cinnamon and the share worked on all machines.

What is going on?

I have been using Ubuntu on and off since Ubuntu08 and exclusively since 2011. But am considering changing to Mint as it appears to do everything else AND share files.

In answer to your question ajgringo619
sorry for the delay but it tool a while to get the code inserted, properly formatted

`testparm -s
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Processing section "[printers]"
Processing section "[print$]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE`

`# Global parameters
[global]
    dns proxy = No
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    map to guest = Bad User
    max log size = 1000
    obey pam restrictions = Yes
    pam password change = Yes
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
    passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
    passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
    server role = standalone server
    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
    syslog = 0
    unix password sync = Yes
    usershare allow guests = Yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb`

`[printers]
    browseable = No
    comment = All Printers
    create mask = 0700
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = Yes`

`[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers`

I have used diff to compare this with the output from the Mint installation and the only difference was a comment, preceded by#

The type of share I would like is read only to anyone on my network including visitors. The linux permissions to all the files, on the share, are rwxr-xr-x with the owner being me.

Comment: Post the results of `testparm -s` (add to your question, please).

Comment: OK, now what kind of access are you looking to provide via Samba?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to using Mint cinnamon 19.2 with no problems and a simpler user experience for guests. Sorry to leave ubuntu.
During the upgrade from my existing mint 19.1 to 19.2 I noticed a comment that ubuntu 18.04 doesn't handle samba very well with recommended mods to smb.conf. I might try these and see if ubuntu then works.
bye bye ubuntu, yes I know mint is ubuntu revamped.